# flutter: how update one item in gridview?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I use GridView in my Flutter's app.  Size my GridView is 30x4(with  different widgets). 
I need to update one widget in my gridView. I have two solutions and I need to choose the best.

1. Update all GridView. It is easy but I think this is not optimal (rebuild the entire grid for one change).
2. Update one widget. it is more complicated. but I know how to do it. This is a [similar example](https://github.com/FetFrumos/ListViewUpdateRow).

what do you advise?

Comment: Update one widget...if it is optimal

Comment: Did you create your GridView with builder? Can you paste some code on how you tried to update it?